# How do I extract the Class labels from neuralnet model in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network

I am using neuralnet in r to train a neural network. The output of the neural network is a series of columns with one column representing one class(204 in my case) and the probabilities of each row being in each class as the values.

I am using max.col to select the class with the highest probabilities, however, the colnames of the columns outputted by the network are just numbers (from 1 to the number of classes). I am wondering how I associate these numbers with the actual labels?

My Code is as follows:

```
Train  <- Embeddings[Sample, ]
Test   <- Embeddings[!Sample, ]

# Oversampling
TrainOversampled <- Train %>%
  group_by(Code) %>%
  do(slice(., sample(n(), 50, replace = TRUE)))

nn <- neuralnet(
  formula = Code ~ .,   # Specify the formula for the network
  data = Embeddings,             # Specify the data frame containing the embeddings and labels
  hidden = c(25),          # Specify the number of hidden neurons in a single hidden layer
  linear.output = F, threshold = 0.05 , stepmax=1e7    # Specify linear output activation    
)

Test <-as.matrix(Test%>%select(-Code))
predictions <- predict(nn, newdata = as.matrix(Test), type="class")
predictionsmaxcol <- data.frame(max.col(predictions))
colnames(predictionsmaxcol)[1] <- "MaxCol"`
```

an extract of the output of the predictions max col is:

```
> predictionsmaxcol$MaxCol

[1]  44 175  49  59  44 169 151  80 155 136 120  57 136 163
```

Whereas I want the output to be the `"Code"` (Character string).

Comment: Is it mandatory to use `neuralnet` or we can use other package also like `nnet`?

Comment: nnet would be fine also

Answer (score 0):

As you have not provided any data, I am using `iris` data like

```
library(neuralnet)

# Split data
train_idx <- sample(nrow(iris), 2/3 * nrow(iris))
Train <- iris[train_idx, ]
Test <- iris[-train_idx, ]

#training model on training dataset
nnet_model <- neuralnet(Species ~ ., hidden = 25, data=Train,
                        linear.output = F, threshold = 0.05 , stepmax=1e7)


#generating predictions
nnet_prediction <- predict(nnet_model, Test)

#You have to name the predicted probabilities according to your dependent variable levels
colnames(nnet_prediction) <- c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica") 
colnames(nnet_prediction)[max.col(nnet_prediction)]
```

**Update**
Using `nnet` you can do

```
library(nnet)

# Split data
train_idx <- sample(nrow(iris), 2/3 * nrow(iris))
Train <- iris[train_idx, ]
Test <- iris[-train_idx, ]

#training model on training dataset
nnet_model <- nnet(Species ~ ., data=Train, size = 25, 
                   decay = 5e-4, maxit = 200)

#generating predictions
nnet_prediction <- predict(nnet_model, Test, type = "class")
```

Comment: Thanks UseR10085, however there are 250 classes in "Code" so its not feasible to manually label them. are you aware of a what to do so in an automate fashion?